# How to make items fill remain space of collection view

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, collectionview, autosize

I have a collection view to show days of selected week and I want items of the collection view to fill remain space with equal size. How can I do this without calculating size in code and setting padding?

```
            <CollectionView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DaysOfWeek}" BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="50" SelectionMode="Single">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="Green">
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{}{0:ddd}'}" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Day}" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

That's my result:https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bPKY.png
That's how I want to do:https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnC5Y.png

Comment: You would need to manually calculate the size of each cell.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can use MathExpressionConverter from Xamarin Community Tools to calculate width of item.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <xct:MathExpressionConverter x:Key="MathExpressionConverter"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

I take width of CollectionView and divide it by 7 and set this value to width of item

```
            <CollectionView x:Name="CollView" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DaysOfWeek}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="50" SelectionMode="Single">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
                        <Grid WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference CollView}, Path=Width, Converter={StaticResource MathExpressionConverter}, ConverterParameter='x/7'}">
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{}{0:ddd}'}" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Day}" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```